# Windows Phone 8 Camera record certain time

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm working on a small app that requires the video camera to record the last 20,30,40,50seconds while its continually previewing on my rectangle. I can record and save as I wish but the movies are really big and I cant have the app recording all the time, I only need the last portion of the movie.

I though of putting frames of the movie in a queue but that would be too expensive in data structures as I'm also saving gps data and accelerometer data. I think I need some sort of a buffer so when the user presses save it saves what is in the buffer as a movie.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not looking for code, just a way round this problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the background timer and invoke the record option at required intervals.